# NextGen Gallery: Display title in the gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I want to display the title in the NextGen gallery. The plugin does not offer an option for that, so I have to somehow go past it, and modify the code.

NextGen Version:2.0.33.

Has anyone got across the same problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stefan - The view folder is in the modules/ngglegacy folder. New version I guess.

As for the gallery title, I modified some code I found here,

http://psychopixi.com/tech/how-to-link-back-to-an-album-in-a-nextgen-gallery/

It's actually for showing breadcrumbs and providing a back button, but if you change the values of the iterators myi and myi2 in lines 10 and 13 it will just output with the title, which you can format as you wish.

As per their suggestion I used the plugin Shortcode Exec PHP to make shortcode which I then placed in my gallery page. You can then place the shortcode for your gallery after.

It's not an elegant solution, and it assumes that the url of your gallery has the name of the gallery in it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $gallery->title ?>
```

Place this in your gallery template file wherever it's needed.

Comment: If i var_dump the $gallery->title it gives me NULL

Comment: Where are you placing this?

Comment: In the nextgen_basic_gallery/templates/thumbnails/index.php

Comment: I have mine in /wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/view/gallery.php and it works fine.

Comment: I saw this answer when I first looked for an answer, but I DON'T HAVE a view folder in the nextgen-gallery.

Comment: Can you upload the plugin somewhere please?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Upload the plugin? Have you not installed the wp plugin?

Comment: I installed it, i have it. But in the version I have in the  /wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery folder i don't have a view folder. The gallery.php file is somewhere else, and if I do what you said there it doesn't work, so I think that you have an older version of the plugin.

Comment: No, I use this one, 2.0.33 on wp 3.6-http://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Comment: On behalf of @wgoodman: That worked until I upgraded to the latest NextGen, when there was a views folder. Does anyone know how to do it with the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem having searched all day on inet.

Your 'view' folder is in the ngglegacy folder of the plugin. You can add `<?php echo $gallery->title ?>` to that file. Then goto Gallery options in your admin area and select gallery.php to show for the Basic Thumbnails.

thats it!